# looping different custom taxonomies with single page template

Tags: wordpress

I have a main custom taxonomy page templates which call "product" it will show all the product in a single page.
But I have lot of sub taxonomies under product wanna show each in different page.
I know I can create as much as taxonomies categories page for each sub category but is there any way I can do it with a single template to fulfill all the looping?

Comment: Why don't you use [`taxonomy-{$taxname}.php`](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/taxonomy-templates/) file instead of creating custom pages for each taxonomy term?

Comment: thanks dude , I used https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/taxonomy-templates/

Comment: Glad i could help, i created an answer feel free to tick it as the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create pages for each taxonomy term, you could create a file called `taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php` in your theme's directory (which `{taxonomy}` is the name of taxonomy you crated) and it will load for each taxonomy term you create. for more information read [Taxonomy Templates docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/taxonomy-templates/).